# To customize my Allure report @Step and @Attachments are not working for TestNG in my local workspace

Tags: report, testng, allure

I wanted to customize my alllure report by adding 3 more extra fields to the xml file (Report) which gets generated in local system.

`@Step` is not working.
I tried by adding `@Step` annotation at parameterized method. But content in the `@Step` annotation is not reflecting in the xml report.

When i searched in google for this query, many were telling to add `AspectJWeaver` dependency in the `pom.xml`.

But, my project is not maven project and i don't have `pom.xml`.
In fact, i have `aspectjweaver-1.8.9` jar in libraries.

Please guide me, is this configuration issue which i have to do to make `@Step` annotation work?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add it as javaagent to your VM options (e.g. in run configuration for IntelliJ IDEA). For win something like that

```
-javaagent:C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.5/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
```